# robot unable to rotate in place for dwa_local_planner

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa, dwa-local-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

****UPDATED****

I am using [dwa_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner) as a local planner and is having some issues while the robot is turning (that is, rotating in place). The robot is able to go forward without any issues and is able to reach the goal within `xy_tolerance` and is able to rotate in place to correct its orientation so that it is within `yaw_goal_tolerance`. I have specified following parameters:

```
max_rot_vel: 1.0
min_rot_vel: 0.8
```

But I am having a problem when the robot has to go to the second goal once robot reaches the first goal and has to turn in place to move towards the second goal. The dwa_local_planner sends `linear.x = 0.0` and `angular.z = 0.31` in this case and hence the robot is unable to turn in place.  This happens when `min_trans_vel = 0.0`. If I specify `min_trans_vel` as 0.1 or 0.2, then the robot is able to turn but in some cases, when the robot has to turn to go to the second goal, it is not able to turn and keeps on going straight at `min_trans_vel` till it reaches the wall and stops. It does not seem to have enough rotational velocity component.

I have specified `min_rot_vel: 0.8` but it looks like the dwa_local_planner is not considering that. Is there any parameter similar to `min_in_place_rotational_vel` (which is there for `TrajectoryPlannerROS`) in case of dwa_local_planner which can be modified for in place rotation in case of `dwa_local_planner`? Or, does anyone have any idea why is this happening and how can it be solved?

**dwa_local_planner_params.yaml**

```
DWAPlannerROS:
  acc_lim_x: 2.0
  acc_lim_y: 0
  acc_lim_th: 3.0
  max_trans_vel: 0.5
  min_trans_vel: 0.0
  max_vel_x: 0.5
  min_vel_x: 0.0
  max_vel_y: 0
  min_vel_y: 0
  max_rot_vel: 1.0
  min_rot_vel: 0.8

  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.15
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

  sim_time: 1.5
  sim_granularity: 0.025
  vx_samples: 10
  vy_samples: 0
  vtheta_samples: 20
  controller_frequency: 10
  penalize_negative_x: true

  path_distance_bias: 1.0
  goal_distance_bias: 0.8
  occdist_scale: 0.01
  forward_point_distance: 0.325
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2
  scaling_speed: 0.25
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2

  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05

  prune_plan: false  

  sim_period: 0.1
  rot_stopped_vel: 0.01
  trans_stopped_vel: 0.01
```

Please let me know if you need more information from me. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210914/robot-unable-to-rotate-in-place-for-dwa_local_planner/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-06-09

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-09**:
So the robot always has to be rotating? What kind of physical setup is that?

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-06-09**:
Sorry if the question is not clear. I meant that robot is able to go straight without any issues but when it reaches the goal and has to correct its orientation, dwa_local_planner does not send enough angular velocity and the robot does not turn, I have improved/updated the original question. TIA

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-09**:
So your driver won't rotate if you send a velocity less than 0.8?

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-06-09**:
@David Lu yeah..if the velocity (angular.z) is less than 0.8 or 0.7, the robot does not rotate. So therefore I set minimum velocity as 0.8.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-23**:
I also have the same problem,my robot does not like slow velocities,isnt it just a problem with the controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We encountered similar problems recently. DWA cannot perform a rotate in spot motion. It will always trying to perform an arc motion, combining trans and rot velocity. However, with fined tuned parameters, it will try to U-turn in a very small radius.

Firstly, as you updated, do not set `min_trans_vel` to 0. I have some warnings in my yaml file.

> ## Warning!   #   do not set min_trans_vel to 0.0 otherwise dwa
>
> will always think translational
> velocities   #   are non-negligible
> and small in place rotational
> velocities will be created.

After that, you may would like trying to tune

> path_distance_bias: 1.0
> goal_distance_bias: 0.8
> occdist_scale: 0.01

These are most important three parameters mentioned in Fox's paper.

> By maximizing solely the clearance and
> the velocity, the robot would always
> travel into free space but there would
> be no incentive to move towards a goal
> location. By solely maximizing the
> target heading the robot quickly would
> get stopped by the first obstacle that
> blocks its way, unable to move around
> it.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2015-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try setting use_dwa to False.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-06-18**:
I have updated my question based on your answer.. Please have a look.. TIA